# Changing Terminal visual theme in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

How can one change the visual style/theme for PyCharm's terminal?

[image]

I've tried looking in the Terminal menu inside settings,

[image]

But as you can see there's no place where I can change the visual themes, is it at all possible?

I'm using PyCharm 3.0.1.

Comment: It looks to me like it's currently a very bare-bones terminal emulator, without any theming. But maybe it would be better to ask in the JetBrains forum.

Comment: @Barmar I ask because you _could_ change themes and such from a now depreciated plugin from jetbrains called command-line-tool. So, I was hoping that I'd get some input from here. Also, this is a great place to ask JB questions since there are many users here, crazyCoder is head of support in Jetbrains and he's a regular on SO.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Navigate to:

- Settings

  - Editor
  - Colors&Fonts

    - Console Colors and Console Font

Comment: Console is quite different from terminal, I'm afraid.

Comment: But it uses the console color scheme:)

Comment: It is not working within intellij 13: I still have a crappy font in my terminal whatever changes I did on the Console font settings.

Comment: Did you close the terminal session (red X on the upper-left)? I found that I didn't get all of the settings changed if I didn't close the session.

Comment: @TedM.Young, you're awesome. Such a simple, dumb thing, but overlooked on my end. Thanks!

Comment: This changes my code window to, but I only wanted the terminal window to be in a different theme

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into 
 - > Preferences
 - > Colors & Fonts 
 - > Console Colors/Console Font

Edit the background color here. If you are not seeing the change immediately, close and reopen your terminal window to refresh.

Answer (score -2):

The terminal on Intellij uses the same font as the Terminal app (OSX).